# KafkaJsonSerializer: Default constructor for case class

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka

I am consuming data from a Kafka topic using the following consumer setup:

```
val consumer = {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "some_consumer_group")
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, streamingConfig.getString("kafka.brokers"))
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[StringDeserializer])
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[KafkaJsonDeserializer[Sample]])
    properties.put("json.value.type",classOf[Sample])
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, streamingConfig.getInt("kafka.maxPollRecords"): java.lang.Integer)
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, streamingConfig.getInt("kafka.sessionTimeoutMs"): java.lang.Integer)
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, streamingConfig.getInt("kafka.heartbeatIntervalMs"): java.lang.Integer)
    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, Sample](properties)
    consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList(topic))
    consumer
}
```

while the payload is represented by the following case class

```
case class Sample(properties: Map[String, String],eventType: String)
```

The problem is that during the deserialization the following errors are produced

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.service.Sample` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{}"; line: 1, column: 2]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.service.Sample` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{}"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

If I was using Java the solution for this is straighforward: Just add a default constructor. What happens in the case of Scala case classes though? I know that the Jackson object mappers can be configured with a `jackson-module-scala` [which takes care of case classes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) but due to the way the `KafkaJsonSerializer` is configured I cannot mess with its object mappers - this is its `configure` method:

```
protected void configure(KafkaJsonSerializerConfig config) {
    boolean prettyPrint = config.getBoolean("json.indent.output");
    this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    this.objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, prettyPrint);
}
```

So how can I go about this error here?

Comment: Is this setup enforced on you, or are you setting it up now? Because if Kafka was handled by some Scala library it would most likely use type classes for codecs (e.g. Circe if you are using Jackson), and avoids all the runtime reflection issues with requiering object to have default constructor and setters for each property.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok  I am setting it up. There is no definite way to do this but most examples out there point to the `KafkaJsonSerializer` or a custom `JsonSerializer`. Do you suggest using another `JsonSerializer`? Based on `spray` or `circe`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: With Akka you can use [Kafka connector](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka-kafka/current/home.html). There is also [Kafka integration for FS2](https://fd4s.github.io/fs2-kafka/). Both links contains documentation with examples. Both approaches are better than using Kafka consumer directly.